# URI not found 404 spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I'm using `intellij` and `spring-boot` to build server application. But it's frequently showing `404 URI not found error`. Specially when I declare `@RequestMapping` in class.

## Error

```
{
    "timestamp": 1519069359705,
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/profile/5"
}
```

## Controller

```
@RequestMapping("/profile")
@RestController
public class ProfileController {
    @Autowired
    private ProfileService profileService;

    @RequestMapping(name = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Profile get(@PathVariable("id") int id){
        return profileService.get(id);
    }
}
```

## Server Log

```
Mapped "{[/profile],methods=[GET]}" onto public ....
```

**Note**: `ProfileController`'s package has several layers. Like `com.company.project.modules.profiles.controller` where `com.company.project` package contains `Application`. I tried `@ComponentScan` but didn't help. Also invalidate `IDE cache`.

Comment: Maybe because the element with id=5 doesn't exist?

Comment: Controller doesn't get hit!

Comment: I have an example which I have been using for couple years. Please take a look as a reference.

https://github.com/bigzidane/springboot-rest-h2-swagger

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use 'value' instead of 'name' in RequestMapping:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```